# Change jar name in a deployed war

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a war file deployed on an old system running on Tomcat6. I need to redeploy it on a new 64-bit server also running Tomcat6. I've done this but in the logs I get an error saying sapjcorfc.dll is not found.

This file is available in the old 32-bit system but the new 64-bit version installs sapjco3.dll and requires sapjco3.jar.

My question is, can I make the war file use  sapjco3.jar as it doesn't have the same name as the old one?

Cheers,
Russ.

Comment: Couldn't understand what you are asking. But, fyi, jar file name doesn't matter, as long as it has all the dependency classes.

Comment: 64-bit version installs sapjco3.dll so where sapjco3.jar come from?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Araggorn, that's good to know. Hrg, I got the sapjco3.jar from their website :
https://websmp207.sap-ag.de/~form/handler?_APP=00200682500000002672&_EVENT=DISPLAY&_SCENARIO=&_HIER_KEY=501100035870000018527&_HIER_KEY=601100035870000225414&_HIER_KEY=601100035870000255982&

The download zip contains the dll and jar file. I'm assuming that the new jars are backwards compatible.